# Traveling with a battery

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

I'm traveling from the US to Switzerland with a layover in Frankfurt / Main (Germany).

I intend to buy a laptop battery in the US for a friend's laptop. I intend to take this battery with me on the trip. 
As far as I know, I cannot have lithium batteries in my checked-in baggage, so I'll be carrying this battery with my carry-on baggage. However, I won't have a laptop for this battery.

Is there a possibility that this might raise an issue? I mean the fact that I'll be carrying a battery but no corresponding laptop for this battery.

Answer (score 2):

For [Lithium batteries with more than 100 watt hours](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/lithium-batteries-more-100-watt-hours) (no date on page)

Says:

> Lithium batteries with more than 100 watt hours may be allowed in carry-on bags **with airline approval**, but are limited to two spare batteries per passenger. Loose lithium batteries are prohibited in checked bags.

So checking with the airline beforehand would be needed if > 100 Watt.

---

[The Top Five Items People Ask About:.. , Batteries,..](https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2018/08/07/top-five-items-people-ask-about-razors-batteries-makeup-shampoo-deodorant) (2018-08-07)

> Consumer-sized lithium ion batteries [no more than 8 grams of equivalent lithium content or 100 watt hours (wh) per battery]. This size covers AA, AAA, 9-volt, cell phone, PDA, camera, camcorder, Gameboy, and **standard laptop computer batteries**.

If less than 100 Watt seems to be generally allowed for Carry-On-Baggage.

No meantion that a corresponding Laptop must exist.

Comment: If it is not obvious from the battery itself that it is a battery and what the capacity is, it might be a good idea to leave it in its original packaging. Although, be prepared to unpack it at security, which might be a hassle depending on how it is packaged. (E.g. it might require a knife to open, which you are hopefully not planning to carry through security.)